# Yii 1.1 excessive amount of queries, how to optimise?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm having a huge issue with Yii, as rendering simple things takes over 10 seconds.

For example:

Controller:

```
public function actionFailed($id=null) {
    if(!is_null($id)) $this->_viewcity=$id;
    $failed = Delivery::model()->findAll('failed IS NOT NULL AND city_id = '.$this->_viewcity.' ORDER BY id DESC');
    $cities = City::model()->findAll('active > 0');
    $this->render('failed',array(
        'failed'=>$failed,
        'cities'=>$cities,
        'city'=>City::model()->findByPk($this->_viewcity),
    ));
}
```

In the view only 
`foreach ($failed as $d)` is used.

Query log: http://jsfiddle.net/kwqabmc0/

How can I optimise this? My SQL server is 23ms ping away and the previously mentioned page takes very long to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are use lazy loading of `Delivery.items` and `Delivery.user` in the view.

Try

```
$failed = Delivery::model()->with('items', 'user')->findAll('failed IS NOT NULL AND city_id = '.$this->_viewcity.' ORDER BY id DESC');
```

or do not use these relations in the view.